# How can I handle different tensor sizes in the forward() method in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm training an [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) model, and I use a window size of 20. However, I need the output tensor to have a shorter length.

This small code fragment illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
def forward(self, x):
    x, _ = self.lstm(x)  # x.size() is [:, :20, :]
    x = self.linear(x)

    x = x[:, :10, :]  # I trim the result to 10.

    return x
```

This code works as intended, but is there a way to initially get (obtained by self.lstm()) the tensor which is [:, :10, :] in size?

I suppose that the current implementation may slow the learning process.

Comment: Just trim your data to a window size of 10.

Comment: you could change 'self.lstm' or 'self.linear'  to output the desired size